# Enable remote desktop (screen sharing) on ethernet while WiFi is connected to internet

Tags: vnc, vino

I have a Ubuntu server connected to internet using WiFi. It is connected to another Windows computer via Ethernet. I setup internet sharing on Ubuntu box using iptables method from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing.
Problem is if I am connected to WiFi as primary connection, vino VNC server cannot be enabled to use Ethernet to share screen. I am able to ping the Ubuntu box from windows and access shared folder. Is there any way to enable vino with this configuration or may be another VNC server that would support it? I tried to install a different VNC server but, I couldn't get it to work yet.

Comment: Which client are you using from Windows.

Comment: I was using realVNC.

Comment: I end up installing Teamviewer and using Local connection. I didn't know I could use local connections with team viewer. It is much faster and easier to configure than VNC.

Answer (score 0):

In the same situation (win 10 & Ubuntu 18.04 I had to change the default value in dconf-editor

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

and checked

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Vino enabled
```

In my PC it was 'No such key “enabled”. **If false** run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled true
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I am using WIn 10 & Ubuntu 18.10. I tried using Win 10 and Win Server. Everything works fine, but my online game would get latency spikes every 5 seconds. I tried with raspberry pi as the server and it did not have latency spikes. Plus accessing files in network share folder on Pi was much faster. But Pi was crashing for some reason after a day or two. This is why i'm trying to use Ubuntu as the server.